# Incorrect value in deserializating Xml to Class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have created the class from XML using Visual Studio 2013 feature "Paste XML as Class". I am deserializing the xml. If I am getting a blank node in xml, in case of Blank xml node, I am getting the corresponding variable of class as "{object}" instead of null:

```
<ADDRESS>
 <LINE1>30 John Islip Street</LINE1> 
 <LINE2 />
 <LINE3 /> 
 <LINE4 /> 
</ADDRESS>

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class ADDRESS
{
    /// <remarks/>
    public string LINE1{get;set;}

    /// <remarks/>
    public object LINE2{get;set;}

    /// <remarks/>
    public object LINE3{get;set;}

    /// <remarks/>
    public object LINE4{get;set;}
}
```

Deserializing code:

```
var reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ADDRESS));
var instance = (ADDRESS)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

For fields LINE2,LINE3,LINE4 we are getting the values as "{object}" instead of null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct behavior. Your xml contains nodes Line2 - Line4, so it is in your class.
If you change types of Line2 - Line4 to string, you can get "" in them. To get null in this properties you should not have this nodes in xml or this nodes should have attribute `nillable='true'`.